# Symmetric Square

Tags: python, matrix, homework

I was given an assignment to ensure that a list was symmetric.

I built it in a way that worked and it passed the tests. But I wanted to see if it could've been written more efficiently and still readable.

**Original question**

> A list is symmetric if the first row is the same as the first column,
>   the second row is the same as the second column and so on. Write a
>   procedure, symmetric, which takes a list as input, and returns the
>   boolean True if the list is symmetric and False if it is not.

**My solution**

```
def symmetric(master):
    master_count = len(master)

    if not master: # checks to see if the list is empty
        return True

    if master_count != len(master[0]): #check to make sure the list is a square
        return False
    i = 0
    while i < master_count:
        j = 0
        while j < master_count:
            print str(master[i][j]) +" "+str(master[j][i])
            if master[i][j] != master[j][i]:
                return False
            j = j + 1 # close the loop
        i = i + 1 # close the loop
    return True
```

**Tests & expected responses**

```
print symmetric([[1, 2, 3],
                 [2, 3, 4],
                 [3, 4, 1]])
#>>> True

print symmetric([["cat", "dog", "fish"],
                 ["dog", "dog", "fish"],
                 ["fish", "fish", "cat"]])
#>>> True

print symmetric([["cat", "dog", "fish"],
                 ["dog", "dog", "dog"],
                 ["fish","fish","cat"]])
#>>> False

print symmetric([[1, 2],
                 [2, 1]])
#>>> True

print symmetric([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [2, 3, 4, 5],
                 [3, 4, 5, 6]])
#>>> False

print symmetric([])
#>>> False
```

Comment: The last output should be `True`, right?

Comment: Your code test with the input [1] will return an error!
don't know how to solve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `range` (or `xrange` for Python 2) to make the code shorter and clearer.

So instead of

> ```
> i = 0
> while i < master_count:
>     j = 0
>     while j < master_count:
>         print str(master[i][j]) +" "+str(master[j][i])
>         if master[i][j] != master[j][i]:
>             return False
>         j = j + 1 # close the loop
>     i = i + 1 # close the loop
> ```

We have

```
for i in range(master_count):
    for j in range(master_count):
        if master[i][j] != master[j][i]:
            return False
```

Actually we're doing twice the amount of work we need to. If `master[i][j] == master[j][i]`, we don't need to check the opposite:

```
for i in range(master_count):
    for j in range(i + 1, master_count):
        if master[i][j] != master[j][i]:
            return False
```

Alternatively, you could use `all` and a generator expression:

```
return all(master[i][j] == master[j][i]
           for i in range(master_count)
           for j in range(i + 1, master_count))
```

I would also reconsider the variable names, e.g. `matrix` instead of `master`, `dim` or `n` instead of `master_count`.

Answer (score 3):

- The variable name `master` doesn't make any sense, as your function accepts a sequence containing sequences you should name it something that makes more sense. For eg we can use `seq` or `iterable` here:
- `row_count` will make more sense than `master_count`.
- `if not master` should be checked first, even before checking the length.
- `if master_count != len(master[0])` can fail we any of the rows after the first row contain different number of items. I've used [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression in my answers below.
- You can totally use a for-loop here, avoid indexing as much as possible in Python. Normal for-loops are more-readable.

---

My first suggestion is going to use indexing only to get the column items. To get the column items for a particular row I've created a function `get_column` that accepts an iterable and an index as its arguments and lazily yield item on at that index from each row of that iterable.

The looping over rows in done using the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, it returns both the index and the current row. We can use this index to get the column items by passing it to `get_column`. Later we [`izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)(returns an iterator) the current row and the column items and check if [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) of the items don't match:

```
from itertools import izip


def get_column(seq, ind):
    for row in seq:
        yield row[ind]


def symmetric(seq):
    if not seq: # checks to see if the list is empty
        return True

    row_count = len(seq)

    #check to make sure the list is a square
    if any(len(row) != row_count for row in seq):
        return False

    for ind, row in enumerate(seq):
        column = get_column(seq, ind)
        if any(row_item != col_item  for row_item, col_item in izip(row, column)):
            return False
    return True
```

---

Another way that doesn't use indexing at all.

Here I've used [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) with splat operator `*`(explained in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)'s docs), it is the recommended way to transpose an iterable in Python. Note that * will unpack the whole iterable at once, so if it was an iterator then we are actually consuming it all at once. The transposed iterator is than passed to [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) so that each of transposed items(`izip` returns tuples) can be converted to list which is then going to us simply compare each row with a column using `!=` operator, i.e no [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) based for-loop for comparison here. It's weird that Python doesn't support [comparing tuple with a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345092/python-why-is-comparison-between-lists-and-tuples-not-supported), hence this conversion to list is required.

But if the array if huge then the conversion to list and then comparing using `!=` is actually going to be slow because it will require at least one complete loop over the tuple to convert it to a list, in that case we can remove `imap` call and within the loop simply compare the items using `izip` and `any()`(added this is comments).:

```
from itertools import izip, imap


def symmetric(seq):

    if not seq: # checks to see if the list is empty
        return True

    row_count = len(seq)

    #check to make sure the list is a square
    if any(len(row) != row_count for row in seq):
        return False

    columns = imap(list, izip(*seq))

    for row, col in izip(seq, columns):
        if row != col:
            return False
    # or
    # columns = izip(*seq)
    # for row, col in izip(seq, columns):
    #     if any(row_item != col_item for row_item, col_item in izip(row, col)):
    #         return False

    return True
```